# How to join with the same table two times in jOOQ?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I have table which have one-to-one relation with another, but there are two of them, src and dst, how to join it right? I did something like that, but not sure this is best practce:

```
 val route = tbl.`as`("route")
 val srcPlace = Tables.PLACE.`as`("srcPlace")
 val dstPlace = Tables.PLACE.`as`("dstPlace")

 val records = dsl
        .select(route.asterisk())
        .select(srcPlace.asterisk())
        .select(dstPlace.asterisk())
        .from(route)
        .join(srcPlace).on(route.SRC_ID.eq(srcPlace.ID))
        .join(dstPlace).on(route.DST_ID.eq(dstPlace.ID))
        .limit(pageable.pageSize)
        .offset(pageable.offset)
        .fetch {
            val r = it.into(route).into(RouteEntity::class.java)
            val sP = it.into(srcPlace).into(PlaceEntity::class.java)
            val dP = it.into(dstPlace).into(PlateEntity::class.java)
            r.srcPlace = sP
            r.dstPlace = dP
            r
        }
```

How to do it better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way (starting from jOOQ 3.17 and [the ability of projecting table expressions as  `SelectField`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/tables-as-selectfield/)) is to just project the tables themselves, e.g.:

```kotlin
dsl.select(route, srcPlace, dstPlace)
   . // query
   .fetch {
       val (r, sP, dP) = it
       // ...
   }
```

In your particular case, you can even simplify things further by using [implicit joins](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/implicit-join/)

```kotlin
// Assuming you named your foreign keys "src" and "dst"
dsl.select(route, route.src, route.dst)
   .from(route)
   .limit(pageable.pageSize)
   .offset(pageable.offset)
   .fetch {
       val (r, sP, dP) = it
       // ...
   }
```

Or even, without the `it` destructuring:

```kotlin
// Assuming you named your foreign keys "src" and "dst"
dsl.select(route, route.src, route.dst)
   .from(route)
   .limit(pageable.pageSize)
   .offset(pageable.offset)
   .fetch { (r, sP, dP) ->
       // ...
   }
```